# OCR software for recognizing product prices in print catalog

Tags: ocr

Is there any software (preferably backed by open-source components) for extracting textual product information from scanned retailer's product catalogs (i.e. bitmaps).

And what is the name of the technical sub-discipline that looks into these types of problems: they presumably require OCR plus some higher-level guided image analysis.

Here is a sample input:

[image]

Comment: I would call that a flyer rather than a catalogue - catalogue is mainly text something like `UPC - vendor code - name - size - price - unit price - extra codes` usually whereas a flyer is graphics with sale prices.

Comment: @NickWilde Yes, please feel free to edit (as I am not a native speaker).

Comment: I don't know if you ever found the answer to this, nor have I... :( but you might find your answers in this [OCR for catalogues- and it's in production](https://www.catalogosofertas.com.ar/ver/ofertas/catalogo-supermercados-buenos-dias-1585639#page=1)? When you hover over the items you see the segmentation.